# How to send json data without template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am learning rails and trying to modify some existing code. The code in question calls a separate server to render a PDF which is downloaded from the browser.
I would like to change it to just download a json file instead when in development.
Chrome appears to download the file but says "Failed - network error". When I inspect the download it seems to have no body in the response.
The server shows:
Completed 200 OK in 77ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 16.7ms)

My controller code looks like this:

```
# if in development, just send the json to check
if Rails.env.development?
  send_data json.to_json, :filename => 'account_statement.json', :type => 'application/json', :disposition => 'attachment'
else  
  begin
    send_data generate_report(json.to_json), :filename => 'account_statement.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'attachment'
  rescue => e
    raise 'Report server is not available, Please try again later'
  end
end
```

Printing the json.to_json to the console does also show a json string, so that seems fine.

How can I debug this further?

Comment: Have you tried using different mime type such as `text/plain` instead of `application/json` for example?

Comment: Unfortunately the result is the same

Comment: Damn... Have you tried different browser such as Safari or Firefox to see if you can reproduce the problem?

Comment: With Safari I get ~/Downloads/account_statement.json.download/account_statement.json which is an empty file. So basically the same result.

Comment: Do you have turbo links enabled?

Comment: Turbolinks gem is commented out in the Gemfile, so I think not.